# Apex Trigger in Salesforce using 2 objects

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce, project requests I keep track of last_id used.
I created 2 SF objects, one holds the last_id other holds total number of ids to assign. I would like user to enter a number and the number will be added to the last_id. Result will be stored in the tracking object.

**Code:**

```
tracking_next_id__c[] btnext = [SELECT last_end_id__c FROM tracking_next_id__c];

for (tracking__c updatedAccount : Trigger.new) 
{
    updatedAccount.next_id__c = btnext[0].last_end_id__c + updatedAccount.total_account__c;
}
```

When I run the trigger; I get error Error:

> Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger getNextId caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: getNextId: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.getNextId: line 11, column 1

Answer (score 0):

After much research, found if I changed my trigger to before update  instead of after update, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you cannot edit a record in after insert trigger.